# Odd return from WlanEnumInterfaces (Windows Native WiFi) in Java

Tags: java, native, jna, wifi

I'm trying to map the Windows Native Wifi API in Java but I'm having problems with the WlanEnumInterfaces function. Basically, this function outputs a WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST structure containing an array of WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO structures.
When I call the WlanEnumInterfaces in my Java program, its return value indicates that the function succeeds, but when I check the number of items in the WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO array, I get inconsistent values like 1367280 or 4000000. This value should be 1 as I have only one wireless interface on my machine.
Here it's my mapping of the WlanEnumInterfaces function:

```
public int WlanEnumInterfaces(
        HANDLE hClientHandle,
        PointerByReference pReserved,
        WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST.ByReference ppInterfaceList);
```

Implementation of WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST:

```
public static class WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST extends Structure {
    public static class ByReference extends WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST implements Structure.ByReference{}
    public int dwNumberOfItems;
    public int dwIndex;
    public WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO[] InterfaceInfo = new WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO[10];


    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"dwNumberOfItems","dwIndex","InterfaceInfo"});
    }
}
```

And part of the code that calls the function:

```
HANDLE wlanHandle = getWlanHandle();
WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST.ByReference ppInterfaceList = new WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST.ByReference();

int ret = Wlanapi.INSTANCE.WlanEnumInterfaces(wlanHandle,null,ppInterfaceList);
System.out.println("Return: " + ret);    
System.out.println("WlanEnumInterfaces->number of items: "+ppInterfaceList.dwNumberOfItems);
```

Does anyone know what is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WlanEnumInterfaces` populates the field you provide it with the address of a struct.  You are passing in the address of a struct rather than the address of an address.

Use `PointerByReference` to get the address of the struct, e.g.

```
PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();
Wlanapi.INSTANCE.WlanEnumInterfaces(handle, null, pref);
WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST list = new WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST(pref.getValue());
```

Then you need a `Pointer`-based constructor for `WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST`, i.e.

```
WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST(Pointer p) {
    super(p);
    this.dwNumberOfItems = p.readInt(0);
    this.InterfaceInfo = new WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO[this.dwNumberOfItems];
    read();
}
```

Comment: I was actually struggling with the fact that I didn't know how to manipulate PointerByReference to get the WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST. The secret is the Pointer-based constructor. Thank you!